# Package naming in a Spring java app

Tags: java, spring, package, naming-conventions, naming

I'm developing a small web app with Spring and java. And came up with a question about package names.

I have a layer separation app, having:

-the "web" layer with my controllers
-the "domain" layer with my model
-the "connector" layer, in charge of doing http communication with external web services
-the "service" layer, with contains my bussiness and app logic.

I have transformers, comparators used for sorting and other classes, all are used inside my service layer, because are part of the bussiness logic. My question is, should the transformers be inside the service package, something like "service.transformer", and same with "servcice.sorting", or should they be a completely separated package, outside the "service" package?

I'd like to hear your opinions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of considerations to be made when packaging your classes. First, where are the classes used? And, second, how should they be packaged? Regarding the first, you say that your transformers, comparators and associated miscellaneous classes are only used by your service classes. If so, then it makes sense to put them inside your service package.

Regarding the second question, you should think about whether they would ever need to be used elsewhere in this project or another. If so, then you might want to package them at a higher independent level. That makes it easier to package them up into their own library for use elsewhere.

If your using a modern IDE, I wouldn't think too hard about it since it is trivial to refactor your code later as needs change. For example, in Eclipse adding and optimizing import statements, or moving classes from one package to another is a few keystrokes.